# Where does the HTTP referer "applewebdata" come from?

Tags: http, referrer

My site uses a web stat service like Google Analytics, it uses a piece of javascript code to log what pages the visitor has visited and the refer url of each visit. I got some referer "applewebdata", wonder where is those visitors from?

Comment: Not programming.

Answer (score 6):

The “applewebdata” URI scheme is used by iOS and Mac OS X instead of the “http” in URIs used for accessing internal resources on the device or computer itself. The visitors likely came to your site whilst using their iOS or Mac OS X device, being refered there by documents stored on the device rather than from a web page.

Answer (score 1):

The referrer is determined from the headers sent by the browser that visits your site.  By convention, this should contain the URL that referred the visitor to your site - but it could be set to absolutely anything.

You may be able to gain more insight by seeing which browser tag accompanies this referrer.